# Mathematical manipulation on object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to manipulate the properties in an object like this:

```
for (property in posts.data) {
    property = property+1+",";
    output += property;
}
document.write(output);
```

The properties are numerical: 0, 1, 2 etc.

I want to get the result 1,2,3 in this case. But instead I get 01,11,21, etc... It seems to treat the property as a text-string rather than a number. Why? And what can I do about it?

Comment: Because all property names are strings. You can convert each of them to a number first.

Comment: how do I convert a string into a number?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Unary '+' operator converts a string into an integer

> ```
> for (property in posts.data) {
>    var t = +property + 1;
>    output += t+",";
> }
> ```

2.Javascript's `parseInt` method

> ```
> for (property in posts.data) {
>     var t = parseInt(property, 10)+ 1;
>      output += t+","; 
> }
> ```

The second argument in the parseInt function call(radix) will tell the function what numeric system to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt` to convert the `property` to integer before adding `1` into it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mPSnL/

Answer (score 1):

`Parse` the `property` variable in `Int`. like `parseInt()`

```
for (property in posts.data) {
    var p = parseInt(property)+1+",";
    output += p;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could force the string to and int

```
for (property in posts.data) {
  var v = parseInt(property, 10) + 1;
  output += v + ",";
}
```